# Scripted Field Kibana Not Working

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to get scripted fields in Kibana to work.

I have two fields in my documents, `customer` and `site`

I'd like to create a new scripted field called `friendly_name` which is `customer+" "+site`

I've tried
`return doc["customer"].value + " "+doc["site"].value`

and it doesn't yield any results.

I've even tried just `return 1` to see if I can get anything to return.

[image: Kibana scripted fields]

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

Scripted fields work with doc_values only and I am guessing that, since this doesn't work for you, your `customer` and `site` field are `text` fields.
From https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-painless-kibana-scripted-fields:

> Both Painless and Lucene expressions operate on fields stored in doc_values. So for string data, you will need to have the string to be stored in data type keyword.

So, you either define your two fields to be `keyword` or you add a subfield to them and in your scrip you use `customer.keyword` and `site.keyword`. And the changed mapping should be:

```
      "customer": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
```